# URL's dinámicas y estáticas en JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, url

```
function mostrardatos(nombre){
        window.location.href='info.php?amor='+nombre;
    }

 a href="javascript:mostrardatos( php echo $row ['amor_id']; ?>)" id="< php echo $row['amor_id']; >
```

este código lo uso en el href que me redirecciona hacia una vista donde muestro la información del registro el problema es que el '31' es el id del registro y me gustaría que saliera algo mas en esa `url` que no llegue hasta hay me explico ?

como haría el trabajo con JavaScript ? esa función es la que uso para que me abra la información ?

y actualmente en la  url me sale asi

> info.php?caja=31 <-- id del producto

me gustaria que  fuese algo como

> info.php?caja=31?daugdasd=?asd me explico ??

si saben pueden ayudarme a a partir del js que les mostré ?

Comment: indow.location.href='info.php?caja='+nombre+'&daugdasd='+valordedaugdasd;  agrego ese "+valordedaugdasd;" y me dice pagina no encontrada

Comment: La única forma que sale ese error es que no exista su archivo info.php o la ruta esté mal indicada. revise tal cuál está mi respuesta y me comenta como va :)

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia de verdad .. no sera tambien por el href ?

Comment: Sí , es verdad. actualicé con este detalle, no es necesario crear la función puede hacerse directamente en el href :)

Comment: listo ya encontre mi error muchas gracias por todo, me sirvio sus informaciones

Comment: seria alguna molestia contactarte por fb ?

Answer (score 2):

La forma de pasar parámetros por URL tiene la siguiente sintaxis

```
pagina.php?paramuno=valoruno&paramdos=valordos&paramtres=valortres
```

Es decir solo el primer parámetro inicia con **?** los demás se concatenan para armar una [Query_string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) ,  para su ejemplo de función sería *(le paso dos parámetro a la función para el ejemplo y se concatena a la redirección)*

```
function mostrardatos(nombre,apellido){
    window.location.href='info.php?amor='+nombre+'&apellido='+apellido;
}
```

Como solo desea redireccionar no hace falta crear una función para esto, simplemente debería setear el `href` de su etiqueta `a` con los valores que tiene desde `PHP` directamente  *(para el ejemplo es necesario que `$row` tenga una clave precio así como `amor_id`)*

```
<a href="<?php echo "info.php?caja=".$row['amor_id']."?precio=".$row['precio'] ?>" >
  Redirección
</a>
```

Comment: function mostrardatos(nombre,precio){
    window.location.href='info.php?amor='+nombre+'&precio='+precio;
}

lo coloque asi como tu ejemplo y me sale un error en la url : 

localhost/danilu/info.php?caja=31&precio=undefined

Comment: No vendría nada mal usar `encodeURIComponent()` para escapar caracteres inválidos.

Comment: listo ya encontre mi error muchas gracias por todo, me sirvio sus informaciones

Comment: te puedo contactar por fb ?

Comment: @programavzla qué bueno, si le ayudó puede marcar como aceptada mi respuesta, de paso leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Solo por este medio podemos interactuar :)   Saludos

Comment: sabes aunque me funcione el url al final me dice undefinid

Comment: @programavzla no es necesario la función , sale esto porque no le pasa correctamente el valor a la función, revise la segunda parte de mi respuesta setear el valor directamente al href :)